# Adding a route on Windows machine for a specific adapter using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on a Windows Server will multiple adapters.
The primary adapter has a default gateway.
Now I need to setup a gateway (Not Default gateway) for the secondary adapter.
Generally I would use a route add command for that specific adapter for which I need to Interface ID which I get by typing the "route print".

However I am not able to find any way to find the Interface ID of the adapter programmatically.
Any options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the InterfaceIndex using either `Win32_NetworkAdapter` or `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` WMI-class. I would use `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` as you could filter on `IPEnabled` and `DefaultIPGateway` to find the active network adapter with no default gateway. Ex:

```
#Get enabled network adapters
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled = 1" |
#With no default gateway or no IPv4 default gateway
Where-Object { $_.DefaultIPGateway -eq $null -or (@($_.DefaultIPGateway -match '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+').Count -eq 0)  } |
Format-Table Caption, InterfaceIndex, IPEnabled, {$_.IPAddress[0]}

Caption                                                  InterfaceIndex IPEnabled $_.IPAddress[0]
-------                                                  -------------- --------- ---------------
[00000002] D-Link DWA-140 Wireless N USB Adapter(rev.B3)              2      True 192.168.1.5  

#Get interfaceindex
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled = 1" |
Where-Object { $_.DefaultIPGateway -eq $null -or (@($_.DefaultIPGateway -match '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+').Count -eq 0)  } |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex

2
```

You could probably add the route using `Win32_IP4RouteTable` or `Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable` but it's probably easier to just use `route add` and use WMI only to get the `InterfaceIndex`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Get-NetIPInterface` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826135.aspx) to retrieve all interfaces. The `ifIndex` property will have the ID you're looking for.

Once you've found the index or alias of the desired interface, use [`New-NetRoute`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826148.aspx) to add the route

---

Prior to Windows Server 2012, use [netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx) or the [`route`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490991.aspx) command

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, this is in Windows 2008 R2, Get-NetIPInterface does not work in 2008 R2